# Correct Auto-Layout Constraints for TableView-Header

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I am pulling my hair out over this - what are the correct Auto-Layout constraints for the middle Label? Somehow my View always wants to grow for full screen size - resulting in the middle label being huge even if the text is just "ASDF"

What I set Up:

**Big Grey Avatar** - Aspect Ratio 1:1, Width >= 140, Height <=180, Leading/Top 16, Trailing to Labels 16
Right side Labels - Trailing to Container >= 16, Horizontal to Avatar 16, Y Postion Top/Bottom to Avatar

**Middle Label** - Top/Bottom to Avatar and first button row - 16, leading/trailing to container 16

**First Button Row** - All have Aspect Ratio 1:1 and Equal Width Height to each other, button1 leading to container 16, last button trailing to container 16

**Second Button Row** - All have Aspect Ratio and Equal Width/Height to First Row counterpart, Vertical Top 16, Bottom to Container all buttons 16

Additional Code in the Class file For the HeaderView.swift

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    self.middleLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.middleLabel.bounds.size.width
}
```

The Storyboard View and ViewController follows this tutorial:
http://roadfiresoftware.com/2015/05/how-to-size-a-table-header-view-using-auto-layout-in-interface-builder/

With simpler Models just having an Avatar and a Label this works out perfectly fine.

[image]

Comment: Just a guess but you probably want to set the content huging priority,

http://krakendev.io/blog/autolayout-magic-like-harry-potter-but-real

This blog post does an awesome job of explaining

Comment: Is this entire view your TableViewHeader? I believe the offending constraint may be the "trailing to container 16" constraint on the Middle Label. This is going to cause the label to grow to the full width of it's container. You could try setting the priority on that constraint to a lower value, or try removing that constraint altogether and allowing the label to hug the content (see above comment).

Comment: Yep this is the TableView header I am loading into the VC later. I also tried to make the trailing >= 16 - but the width is not my problem - its the height that does bother me - the HeaderView somehow always wants to be fullscreen size and the implements constraints accordingly